# not getting the specific result json object and how to compare the two string's

Tags: android, json

i want to get only gender but it shows {"face":[{"gender": {"value": "Male"}}]} 
i only want gender
please help me how it solve `JSONArray jArray = rst.getJSONArray("face");
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
String gender=jArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("attribute").getString("gender");
String jsonText;
jsonText = gender;
textview2.setText("GENDER" + jsonText);`

Comment: Firstly Please validate json mentioned in question on this [link](http://pro.jsonlint.com).Because JSON mentioned in question is wrong check response once.

Comment: @Anil i am using api for the result

Comment: Your json should be like this **{"face":[{"gender": {"value": "Male"}}]}**

Comment: @Anil okay. then how can i fetch the desire value ?

Comment: Check the below answer with proper json result and Let me know if any error

Answer (score 1):

Check this code:-

1. Case 1:This code generate only one toast

   ```
   String result = "{\"face\":[{\"gender\": {\"value\": \"Male\"}}]} ";
   try {
       JSONArray objJsonArray = new JSONObject(result).getJSONArray("face");
       String gender = new JSONObject(objJsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("gender")).getString("value");
       Toast.makeText(this, "Gender is==>" + gender, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. Case 2:-This code generate two toasts.

   ```
   String result = "{\"face\":[{\"gender\": {\"value\": \"Male\"}},{\"gender\": {\"value\": \"Female\"}}]}";
   try {
       JSONArray objJsonArray = new JSONObject(result).getJSONArray("face");
       for (int i = 0; i < objJsonArray.length(); i++) {
           String gender = new JSONObject(objJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("gender")).getString("value");
           Toast.makeText(this, "Gender is==>" + gender, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Hope it solves your problem

Comment: thanks for your solution . but your code only give's me "male" value. i want male or female from the string

Comment: @farhan Its giving you the **result** as the **value of gender coming in the response**.Here I am taking your json as just example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the last line:
textview2.setText("GENDER" + jsonText.value);

Comment: what is 'value' here ?

Comment: The result that's being returned is an object.  This object is a key value pair.  An example of a json object is:<br><br>

Comment: It is the value of the gender field of the json object.

Comment: can you explain more with above example ?

Answer (score 0):

On this line you are getting the entire array:

```
JSONArray jArray = rst.getJSONArray("face");<br>
```

A JSONArray is an Array of json objects.
The json object is a name value pair.
It looks like this:

```
jArray[{name:”John” , gender:”male”}, 
{name:”jane” , gender:”female”}, 
{name:”Mike” , gender:”male”}]<br>
```

This next line loops through the array that you have.  Each time pulling a different json object:
1st time through = [{name:”John” , gender:”male”}
2nd time through = {name:”jane” , gender:”female”}
3rd time through = {name:”Mike” , gender:”male”}
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) { String 
On the first look i = 0
This following line is saying: retrieve the json data where the name is gender.
This returns **{gender:”male”}** 
 “gender” being the name, “male” being the value.

```
gender=jArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("attribute").getString("gender").value; <br>
String jsonText; jsonText = gender; 
textview2.setText("GENDER" + jsonText);
```

I believe there are other more efficient ways to handle this same code, but I hope this helps none the less.

Comment: can you tell me how to compare json string .something like if gender is male it will show "yes it is male" in toast else "female "..

Comment: i have teried your concept but it shows error when i put value, but there is method called valueof().what should i write inside value of ?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("face");
        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            String gender = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("gender").getString("value");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

if you have JsonArray length 1 then no need of for loop just replace i with 0

Comment: thank you . org.json.JSONException: No value for gender

Comment: @farhan _string_ is only for your understanding. In actual it is a json response string

Comment: {"face":[{"gender":{"value":Male"}]} in this response error look properly

Comment: " Male " required quotes

Comment: W/CursorWrapperInner: Cursor finalized without prior close()
12-08 16:42:01.417 18297-18297/myproject.demofacedetection W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for gender
12-08 16:42:01.417 18297-18297/myproject.demofacedetection

Comment: but if this is json response then then get object why you are try to getting string

Comment: @Piyush can i have your e-mail id ?

Comment: refer this ----> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object?rq=1

Comment: @DharaPatel please provide me your e-mail so that i can give you my code for just simple check  as i am totally new to android . well my e-mail is mohdfarhantahir@gmail.com

Comment: http://www.skholingua.com/android-basic/android-app-components/resources